# Insert array values + single form values into all rows

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to insert values from a form into my mysql database. I have single value forms + array values from the form. How can I insert the array values into my database with the single form values attached to all rows?

The HTML:

```
Start:<br>
    <input type="text" name="start" id="start">

End:<br>
    <input type="text" name="end" id="end">

<input type="text" name="item[]" placeholder="Manufacturer #" /><br>

    <input type="text" name="description[]" placeholder="Description" /><br>

    <input type="text" name="item[]" placeholder="Manufacturer #" /><br>

    <input type="text" name="description[]" placeholder="Description" /><br>

    <input type="text" name="item[]" placeholder="Manufacturer #" /><br>

    <input type="text" name="description[]" placeholder="Description" /><br>
```

The PHP:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
            {
                $link = mysql_connect('localhost',     'user', 'pass');
if (!$link) {
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("mydb") or die(mysql_error());
echo 'Connected successfully';

$query = "INSERT INTO agreement (start, end, item_number, item_description) VALUES ";
foreach($_POST['item'] as $i => $item) 
{ 
  // Get values from post.
  $item = mysql_real_escape_string($item);
  $description = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['description'][$i]);
  $start = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['start'][$i]);
  $end = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['end'][$i]);

  // Add to database
  $query = $query." ('$start','$end','$item','$description') ,";
}
$query = substr($query,0,-1); //remove last char
$result = mysql_query($query);
            }
```

I will be changing the code to mysqli/pdo, I know that the current code is unsecure.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `$_POST['start']` and `$_POST['end']` without array access since they will be the same each time.  You can use array access for item and description.

Comment: Okay, it worked. For whatever reason it hadn't worked earlier...must have been an error in my prevous code. Thank you!

Comment: @hek2mgl instead of `$_POST['start'][$i]` just use `$_POST['start']`